# JSONObject in Velocity

Tags: java, json, velocity

I have Java code that returns a `JSONObject`

I then retrieve it in velocity like this.
 
`#set ($JSON = $patient.toJSON($displayedFields))`

It displays fine, however there is one problem.
I cannot do this:

```
$JSON.put("test", "test")
```

Instead of adding ("test", "test") to $JSON it literally outputs `$JSON.put("test", "test")`

How can I add objects to `JSONObject` in velocity?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. (I just didn't pay enough attention)

The `(test, test)` **does** get put into the JSON.
And to prevent `$JSON.put("test", "test")` from outputting itself,

```
#set ($discard = $JSON.put("test", "test"))
```

Comment: Andrey, Any idea on how to parse string into JSONArray? I have been struggling a lot on this. I tried using #evaluate but no success

Comment: what methods does JSONArray have? Does it have an `.add()`?